# Best Way to Store data for retrieval in my system

Tags: php, database

I am making a booking system in php. I'm currently after some advice on the best way to store items in the database. I currently have 3 tables:

```
Table 1 = Hire Stock (Primary Key = asset_id)
```

(contains fields specific to the items such as size, weight, power consumption

```
Table 2 = Project  (Primary Key = project_id)
```

(contains the project start date, end date, customer name.)

```
Table 3 = availability  (Primary Key = asset_id)
```

(Everytime an item is added to a project, it is stored here with it's project id)

I need the ability to be able to search through every item in the inventory, and check that it is available for hire when it is needed. If I have to loop through every item comparing date ranges it's going to take ages. Are there better ways to store the data? Better ways to search through it?

Comment: A Hire Item is *consumed* for the duration of a project? Availability sounds more like AssignedToProject to me and seems a bit confusing - is this the desired goal? Also, "comparing date ranges" likely is "using a SQL set operation with [index-based] range comparisons" so it's not necessarily going to "take ages" here. The more complicated sort of operation is to find which ranges *are* free, not to find an overlap of ranges (or a single range over a set of ranges).

Comment: First rule of programming: first make it work then optimize later. I suggest you first try your approach and see if the performances are miserable then optimize. Also trying to design your data with your code in mind isn't probably a good idea: it create dependencies between the model and the code, so when you have to modify the code, you'll start worrying if the model isn't broken. Last for text search consider using Sphinx and for other go with normal SQL, just impose more restriction, like user has to specify the date range.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema seems sensible. Just join the tables correctly and test that your asset_id is not in those assigned to any project whose date range overlaps the period of the new project you need it for.
Assuming you've created the new project and want to assign products to it.

You want a query that is something like this:

```
$query= "select * from Hire_Stock h ".
"Where h.asset_id not in ".
"( Select a.asset_id from availability a, Project p2, Project p1 ".
"Where p1.project_id = :new_proj ". // The id of the new/planned project
"and p2.project_id != p1.project_id ".
"and p2.end_date >= p1.start_date ".
"and p2.start_date <= p1.end_date ".
"and a.project_id = p2.project_id )";

// using oracle oci

$pok=oci_parse($conn,$query);

if (!$pok) die("Query ($query) Failed!<br>");

oci_bind_by_name($pok,':new_proj',$new_proj,-1);

$res=oci_execute($pok);

While ($hs_row=oci_fetch_array($pok),OCI_ASSOC)
(
  extract($hs_row);
  :
)
```